# VS2010 failing build with unexpected exit code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have my first VS2010 solution with Microsoft tests (ie not nUnit tests). My build is failing on the build server with the error

```
TF270015: 'MSTest.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.
```

What does this mean? Has a test failed? Have I set something up wrong? Is MS telling me to go back to nUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/563602/tf270015-mstest-exe-returned-an-unexpected-exit-code-expected-0-actual-1) resolved in [KB983504](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB983504) hotfix.